# Simple Math game - Android

Tags: java, android, math

I'm new to android. I tried creating a math puzzle. Once the user hits start, two numbers are randomly generated and there are four buttons where the answers are shown. However only one is correct and the others are incorrect. It works fine if there is only one operation allowed like addition or subtraction. However when I allow addition, subtraction and multiplication, I get duplicate answers in the buttons. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong. The code below works fine as only addition is allowed.

```
    public void generateQuestion(){

    Random rand = new Random();

    int a = rand.nextInt(21);
    int b = rand.nextInt(21);

    sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(a) + "+" +Integer.toString(b)); //sumTextView shows the operation on the screen
    locationOfCorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(4);
    answers.clear();
    int incorrectAnswer;
    for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
        if(i==locationOfCorrectAnswer){

            answers.add(a+b);

        }   else {

            incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(41);
            while(incorrectAnswer == a+b){

                incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(41);

            }
            answers.add(incorrectAnswer);

        }

    }

    button0.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
    button1.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(1)));
    button2.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(2)));
    button3.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(3)));

}
```

The code below doesn't work.

```
public void generateQuestion(){

    Random rand = new Random();

    int a = rand.nextInt(21);
    int b = rand.nextInt(21);

    ArrayList<String> mathOperations = new ArrayList<String>();
    mathOperations.add("+");
    mathOperations.add("-");
    mathOperations.add("X");

    String randomOperator = mathOperations.get(rand.nextInt(3));

    locationOfCorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(4);
    answers.clear();
    int incorrectAnswer;
   for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
        if(i==locationOfCorrectAnswer){
            if(randomOperator.equals("+")){
                a = rand.nextInt(21);
                b = rand.nextInt(21);
                sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(a) + randomOperator +Integer.toString(b));
                answers.add(a+b);
            }else if(randomOperator.equals("-")){
                a = rand.nextInt(21);
                b = rand.nextInt(21);
                if(a>b){
                    answers.add(a-b);
                } else{
                    sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(b) + randomOperator +Integer.toString(a));
                    answers.add(b-a);
                }

            }else if(randomOperator.equals("X")){

                a=rand.nextInt(14);
                b=rand.nextInt(14);
                sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(a) + randomOperator +Integer.toString(b));
                answers.add(a*b);
            }
        }

        else {

                if(randomOperator.equals("+") || randomOperator.equals("-")) {
                    incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(61);
                    while(incorrectAnswer == a+b || incorrectAnswer == a-b ){
                        incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(61);
                }
                    answers.add(incorrectAnswer);

                } else{
                    incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(200);
                    while(incorrectAnswer == a*b){
                        incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(200);
                    }
                    answers.add(incorrectAnswer);
                }
        }
    }

    button0.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
    button1.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(1)));
    button2.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(2)));
    button3.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(3)));

}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you are just generating random numbers for the incorrect answers but I can't see any code that attempts to make sure they are unique. Can you indicate clearly why you think there shouldn't be duplicates and what code you think is doing that?

Comment: :In the first bit of code, this ensures that there are no duplicates:                                                            
                                                                                  
                  while(incorrectAnswer == a+b){

                incorrectAnswer = rand.nextInt(41);

            }                                                                                                 
     I'm not able to figure out the code when other operations are included.

Comment: Did you write this code? Because that's certainly not what I think that does. I think that makes sure that your incorrect answers don't happen to randomly be the correct answer. I would have expected if you run the original enough times you'd see duplicates there too. My maths suggests there is a roughly 8% chance of getting a duplicate in your original code...

Comment: yes.....just tried to replicate what works for the first bit of code